# Glassfish RESTful services app

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I have a RESTful web app made in JavaEE using Glassfish 4.1. Have a connection to a MySql DB and an OrientDB. While the app is running from time to time I get this errors:

```
Severe:   Exception in thread "Timer-20"
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.profiler.OAbstractProfiler$MemoryChecker.run(OAbstractProfiler.java:69)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Severe:   Exception in thread "Timer-21"
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.profiler.OAbstractProfiler$MemoryChecker.run(OAbstractProfiler.java:69)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Even those errors are not  breaking the server, I still want to know from where do they come from. I don't understand why this is happening. Don't know where to look. Hope someone can help, thank you.

Comment: Seems to be that some obscure profiler from OrientDB is messing with the class loader?

Comment: Thing is, I have OrientDB integrated in my app for some time now and never seen this problem until now... Single change I did to it, is that I upgraded it from 1.7.4 to 2.0.8. Can it be from the updated libraries ? Or any other idea where to look ?